# JAVA: Indexed map with duplicates

Tags: java, dictionary

I want to get a map with order and duplicates.

```
Map<String, Boolean> map = ?;

map.put("abc", true);
map.put("cba", true);
map.put("cba", true);
map.put("bca", false);
map.put("bac", false);
map.put("bca", true);
map.put("cab", true);
map.put("cba", true);
map.put("cba", false);
map.put("cba", true);

System.out.println(map);
```

I used LinkedHashMap, but It doesn't allow duplicates.

```
Expected:  {abc=true, cba=true, cba=true, bca=false, bac=false, bca=true, cab=true, cba=true, cba=false, cba=true}
Retrieved: {abc=true, cba=true, bca=true, bac=true, cab=true}
```

Is there any implementation of map interface to achieve my goal?

**UPD**

Guava MultiMap doesn't fit into my issue.

```
Multimap<String, Boolean> map = ArrayListMultimap.<String, Boolean>create();
```

It prints

```
{cab=[true], abc=[true], cba=[true, true, true, false, true], bac=[false], bca=[false, true]}
```

**UPD2**

I found solution. `Apache Commons` provides Tuple type `Pair`.

So my code may look like this

```
List<Pair<String, Boolean>> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(new ImmutablePair("abc", true));
list.add(new ImmutablePair("cba", true));
list.add(new ImmutablePair("cba", true));
list.add(new ImmutablePair("bca", true));
list.add(new ImmutablePair("bac", true));
list.add(new ImmutablePair("bca", true));
list.add(new ImmutablePair("cab", true));
list.add(new ImmutablePair("cba", true));
list.add(new ImmutablePair("cba", true));
```

And now it prints

```
[(abc,true), (cba,true), (cba,true), (bca,true), (bac,true), (bca,true), (cab,true), (cba,true), (cba,true)]
```

But I'm still sure that it just should be some good implementation of proper map.

Comment: Just put an array of boolean as the value, and fill it for each key. " A map cannot contain duplicate keys" http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: If there is one, it violates the interface. From the Map's interface Javadoc: "An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value." What you want, is no map.

Comment: Consider Guava's Multimap.

Comment: Or Apache's [MultiValueMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiValueMap.html#MultiValueMap%28%29).

Comment: I suspect Guava's LinkedListMultimap would do the job where ArrayListMultimap would not.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to store an ordered list with duplicates.

```
List<String> map = new ArrayList<>();

map.add("abc" + '=' + true);
map.add("cba" + '=' + true);
map.add("cba" + '=' + true);
map.add("bca" + '=' + false);
map.add("bac" + '=' + false);
map.add("bca" + '=' + true);
map.add("cab" + '=' + true);
map.add("cba" + '=' + true);
map.add("cba" + '=' + false);
map.add("cba" + '=' + true);

System.out.println(map);
```

To create a Tuple class you can do

```
public class Tuple<L,R> {
    private L left;
    private R right;

    Tuple(L left, R right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public static <L, R> Tuple<L, R> of(L left, R right) { 
        return new Tuple<>(left, right); 
    }

    public L left() { return left; }
    public R right() { return right; }

    public String toString() { return left + "=" + right; }

}
```

However, in Java it is generally preferred to give this class and field names a meaningful name and type instead of having tuples of generic data with no meaning attached.

Comment: I want something like Tuple in Scala. Is it possible to set List<Tuple>?

Comment: @barbara yes, though there is not a built in one, you can create one

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are concerned about the format of the output that you print in your map.  If that is the case, then you could use the implementations already in place and simply override the `toString()` method.

If for some reason you would need information about the the absolute order in which entries were entered to your map, you would need to write on implementation yourself that does this for you, since using current implementations would only keep the ordering relative to each key, but not the absolute order.